# Batch file start program where application name is more than one word

Tags: batch-file

OK so having trouble with my batch script. Basically it wont run a program if the program is more than one word, even though I've put " " around the word, if anyone can offer some advice to a novice it would be appreciated:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Claro Software\ClaroRead Plus"
start "ClaroRead Plus.exe"
```

This doesn't work however, the below does work:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Claro Software\ClaroRead Plus"
start ClaroUp.exe
```

To make things even more strange this also doesn't work:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Claro Software\ClaroRead Plus"
start "ClaroUp.exe"
```

Am I being totally stupid here and missing the most obvious of points or is there something else I should be doing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first quoted string for the `start` command is assumed to be a console window title. If you're not starting a console application, you can write:

```
start "" "ClaroRead Plus.exe"
```